# Wire size for 125amp subpanel ,30'underground

Tags: electrical

125amp subpanel off of a 200 Amp main
30'ft run between panels
Underground wire.
What size wire would be required?

Comment: What is the actual load on the subpanel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Wire size depends on the size of the breaker powering the sub panel, not the size of the sub panel.  Can have a 20 amp breaker powering the panel or up to a 125 amp breaker.

Comment: Can you post the loads this subpane is intended to serve?

Answer (score 3):

The "125" figure is the subpanel's bus rating.  It is a "never exceed" redline, not a recommendation.  The circuit size (and thus the wire size) can be any size less than or equal to 125A.  It must satisfy your loads after adjustments are applied.

Subpanels come only in a few sizes, and your #1 concern when picking a subpanel is "plenty of breaker spaces" - running out of breaker spaces is costly.  As such you typically grab a 125A or 200A panel *for the breaker spaces* ... and then it is perfectly common to have 30A, 60A or 90A breakers feeding a 125A panel, with wire appropriate to those breakers.

One popular size is 2-2-2-4 aluminum which is good for 90A. That satisfies almost any imaginable need, including virtually all multi-car [EV charging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s) and then some.

A Load Calculation should be done on the loads which will be served in the garage, and another Load Calculation should be done on all loads served out of the main panel.  One cannot simply stack more and more loads on a panel without thinking about this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to feed it 125A, 1 AWG copper if you like wasting money, 2/0 AWG Aluminum (good for 135A, but 1/0 is only good for 120A) if you don't like wasting money.

Assumes 75°C terminations (normal) and suitable wire or cable (but use wire, in conduit) for 75°C or greater (also normal.)

Unless, of course, the breaker feeding it is not 125A - a 90A breaker would permit 2-2-2-4 aluminum mobile home feeder at a *considerable* cost advantage. The breaker feeding the panel can be **any size up to** the panel size, it does not need to match. The breaker feeding it must be sized to protect the wire. Smaller breaker permits smaller wires. Breaker and wires should be sized to fit the actual calculated load (or greater) at the sub-panel.